# Vue.js how to save in cache element from an array which is added in form

Tags: javascript, vue.js, local-storage

I have a problem with saving my input to the cache memory. I tried to use the `mounted` method, but it isn't working as I would like to because it is not saving the last input in the memory, when I refresh the page the last input disappears. Maybe I'm doing something wrong because I just started learning Vue day ago. Could someone explain to me what is wrong here or how to should I write it?

```
export default {
  name: 'Skills',
  data() {
    return {
      skill: '',
      skills: [
        { 'skill': 'Vue.js' },
        { 'skill': 'Frontend Developer' }
      ]
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    if (localStorage.skill) {
      this.skill = localStorage.skill;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addSkill() {
      this.$validator.validateAll().then((result) => {
        if (result) {
          this.skills.push({skill: this.skill})
          this.skill = '';
        } else {
          console.log('Not valid')
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the code I am using from an example. My v-model in the input is skill. How to write a method which will save the last input in cache correctly? I would like to enter a new skill to the array and when the page refresh wants to still have the value in the array. Is it possible if yes how to do it? I'm really a fresh person in vue.

Comment: "It isn't working as I would like to" is not very useful as a problem description, because it would require mind reading to figure out *what you would like it to do*. Could you edit your question and edit in (1) what currently happens and (2) what you want to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not about Vue.js, but about localStorage.
This is solution

```
export default {
  name: 'Skills',
  data() {
    return {
      skill: '',
      skills: [
        { 'skill': 'Vue.js' },
        { 'skill': 'Frontend Developer' }
      ]
   }
},


  mounted() {
    const skillsList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('skillsList')) || []
    if (skillsList.length > 0) {
      this.skills = skillsList;
      this.skill = skillsList[skillsList.length - 1];
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addSkill() {
      this.$validator.validateAll().then((result) => {
        if (result) {
          this.skills.push({skill: this.skill})
          localStorage.setItem('skillsList', JSON.stringify(this.skills))
          this.skill = '';
        } else {
          console.log('Not valid')
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```